# Event scheduler MySql without expired time

Tags: mysql

I read article about the event scheduler on MySql.Then I got this structure,

```
CREATE
[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
EVENT
[IF NOT EXISTS]
event_name
ON SCHEDULE schedule
[ON COMPLETION [NOT] PRESERVE]
[ENABLE | DISABLE | DISABLE ON SLAVE]
[COMMENT 'comment']
DO event_body;
```

I got some interested thing to know about it, 
1. Could this event schedule havent expired time?
2. What is the ENABLE | DISABLE | DISABLE ON SLAVE mean?

Any respon will be appreciate,Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. *Could this event schedule havent expired time?* Use - `ON COMPLETION PRESERVE`
2. *What is the ENABLE | DISABLE | DISABLE ON SLAVE mean?* ENABLE/DISABLE - means event is active/inactive.

DISABLE ON SLAVE (from the documentation) - *is set for the status of an event on a replication slave to indicate that the event was created on the master and replicated to the slave, but is not executed on the slave.*

Comment: so its mean, that if i didnt use - ON COMPLETION PRESERVE the event just run once?

Comment: There are two types of events: one-time and recurrent. One-time will be dropped just after running. Recurrent event has end date property `ENDS`; so, this event will be dropped after specified end date.